# the state variable in class component is undefined while i try to retrieve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

i have this class component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/App.css';
import { openDB } from 'idb';

class MensaInfo extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            id: 0,
        };
    }


    getMensaId = async () => {
        var db = await openDB('PWA_DATA', 2);
        var transaction = db.transaction(["user"], "readonly");
        var store = transaction.objectStore('user');
        var mensa = await store.get('lieblingsmensa');
        this.id = mensa['lieblingsmensa'];
        console.log(this.id)
        db.close()
    }

    fetchMensa = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(`https://openmensa.org/api/v2/canteens/${this.id}/`);
        const info = await data.json();
    }

    update = () => {
        this.getMensaId()
        this.fetchMensa()
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.addEventListener('load', this.update());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="dive">
                {this.id}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default MensaInfo;
```

i have an id in my idb that i try to use for an api call, i can get the id from the idb and save it as the state it variable, when i try to use it in my api call function it is shown as undefined, not even the 0 i set it at is shown. the console log in getmensaid is showing me the correct value, but i cant use it for the api
In a different component it is working this way, but in this it aint working.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see you never call this.setState.

```
getMensaId = async () => {
    var db = await openDB('PWA_DATA', 2);
    var transaction = db.transaction(["user"], "readonly");
    var store = transaction.objectStore('user');
    var mensa = await store.get('lieblingsmensa');
    // I think the problem is here
    this.setState({id: mensa['lieblingsmensa']});
    //this.id = mensa['lieblingsmensa'];
    console.log(this.id)
    db.close()
}
```